# Update not wrapped in act() with multiple fetch requests using SWR

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, swr

I have a test where if `/endpoint1` fails, an error message should be displayed. The test passes however I get the following error from React Testing Library:

```
Warning: An update to HomePage inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
```

Here's the snipper for clarity. You can see I'm using [SWR](http://swr.vercel.app/) to send requests. I'm mocking requests using [Mock Service Worker](https://mswjs.io/).

```js
export default function App() {
  const { data: data1, error: error1 } = useSwr("/endpoint1")
  const { data: data2, error: error2 } = useSwr("/endpoint2")

  if (error1 || error2) {
    return <Error />
  }

  return <Success />
}
```

The error is present because `/endpoint2` resolves after `/endpoint1`, causing the component to rerender. I believed that cancelling the second request once the first one errors would work. I made a wrapper around `useSwr()` that used `AbortController()` and exposed an `cancel()` function however the same error would occur with this snippet:

```js
export default function App() {
  const { data: data1, error: error1, cancel: cancel1 } = useCancellableSwr(
    "/endpoint1"
  )
  const { data: data2, error: error2, cancel: cancel2 } = useCancellableSwr(
    "/endpoint2"
  )

  if (error1 || error2) {
    if (!data1 || !error1) cancel2()
    if (!data2 || !error2) cancel1()
    return <p>Error</p>
  }

  return <p>Success</p>
}
```

For some reason, even after cancelling one endpoint, it still resolves and causes a rerender. Am I missing something here? Thanks

**Edit:**

Here's the failing test:

```js
  test("An error shows if unable to fetch /endpoint1", async () => {
    mockServer.use(
      rest.get("/endpoint1", (_, res, ctx) => res(ctx.status(500)))
    )

    mockServer.use(
      rest.get("/endpoint2", (_, res, ctx) => res(ctx.status(200)))
    )

    render(<App />)

    const error = await screen.findByText("Error")
    expect(error).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
```

And my custom fetcher function:

```js
async function serverFetch(endpoint) {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080" + endpoint)
  
  const body = response.json()

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw  new Error("An error occurred while fetching the data.")
  }

  return body
}
```

Comment: Could you add the code for the failing test as well, please?

Comment: Why there is no `fetcher` function for `useSWR`? Do you use the original `useSWR` hook or your custom version `useSwr`?

Comment: @juliomalves I've just updated the question to add the failing test

Comment: @slideshowp2 I'm using a custom fetcher, I've added it to the above question

Comment: You're missing an `await` in your `serverFetch` function: `const body = await response.json()`.

Comment: @juliomalves I don't believe that I need to await it since SWR requires a promise to be returned

Comment: It's not visible from the code you posted where `serverFetch` is being used. Could you add that to the question?